# Looking for polite common ways to say that a baby had a defecation

Tags: word-usage

I found some ways to say that a baby had a defecation, but I'm not sure which of them common and which of them will cause immediate laughing or to raise eyebrows.

As I understand, while seeing a physician he may ask it in a formal way: Did the baby **had a defecation**?

While mother or father may say to each other about their baby: "I think she **pooped**". I also found "I think Dillon **did a doodie**", "See if she **made a stinky**".

I am looking for the common but **polite** ways (=not rude) to ask a little child  or about him if he had a defecation.

Comment: You can simply ask if there's poopie in the diaper. It will rely on how (tone, gesture) you ask it, I think.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking *to* a child or baby, then all of those options seem fine. A few others are

- Did you go [number two](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/number-two)?
- Did you [doo-doo](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/doo-doo)?
- Did you [go potty](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+potty)?

I'm sure there are many others.

Usually, the younger the child, the more likely you are to speak to them in [baby talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_talk). So really, many, if not most or all, euphemisms for pooping should be fine if you talk to the child that way.

If you're talking to an adult, then most of the options do start to sound a little silly, especially the ones ending in [*-ie* or *-y*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-y?s=t). Of course, you could still use them in a lighthearted or playful manner. In most cases though, *poop* seems like a good option: not formal, but not too informal or silly either.

Comment: In Britain, we often say "did you drop off a job lot?". In my house we say we had a meeting with Mister Brown.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. From the link you left it seems that doo-doo is a noun,  so maybe it should be "Did you *do* doo-doo?" Isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I've never heard either of those phrases, though I would understand in context.  I think they may be more local than you think.

Comment: The hospital staff at one hospital call the mortuary 'Rose Cottage', when talking to the trolley guys on the phone.

Comment: James K - "I think they may be more local than you think." The 'job lot' one is common in Bristol and SW England.  A 'job lot' is UK business talk for a bulk amount of goods, bought a a discount, and taken or delivered (dropped off) all at once, and 'jobbie' is Scottish slang for a turd; the Mr Brown one is my own invention, although staff in UK hospitals, when they wish to talk about an incontinence incident without humiliating the patient, sometimes talk about 'brown alerts' and 'yellow alerts'.

Comment: @JudiciousAllure I was surprised not to find an entry for the verb _to doo-doo_. I felt like that's common enough (in AmE) to get an entry. If I find an entry, I will update my answer. However, you are also correct. "Do a doo-doo" should be acceptable as well.

Answer (score 2):

We don't, even in medical contexts, tend to be very formal about baby poo.

> Has he done a poo> / Have you done a poo?

This is simple and polite. You could use this with a doctor.

I doubt any doctor would use "defecation" with a patient.  The doctor's expression could be "moved his bowels".

There are many many ways that children use to talk about poo, and that adults use to talk to children. Some are only used in one family.  It is unlikely that a learner would be *to* a young child (that only speaks English) about their poo.

Comment: It's likely that a learner who wants his young brother (or his son)  to learn English as a second lamguage:) One of the ways is to talk to him naturally about everything he is spoken in his native language.